# Floated image in left and right alternative group and text vertically align middle in an unknown height of div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the text vertically align middle in an unknown height of div with a floated image. The first and third div group of 'groupsection2', image will float to left; and the second and forth group of 'groupsection2', image float to right:

```
<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared any of your CSS code. You also seems to be missing a closing `</div>` tag in each code block.

Here's a suggestion to achieve what I think you're trying to do (works on IE9+):

**HTML**

```
<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="groupsection2 clear">
<div class="groupfeature">
<span><img src="testing-images/antec-quality-h230.png" alt="" height="230"/></span>
<div class="feature-content">
<h3>Reliability you can count on Reliability you can count on</h3>
<p>EA-380D Green is backed with AQ3 - Antec Quality 3 year parts and labor warranty, and you get   
unlimited access to Antec’s incomparable technical support and customer service</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.feature-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/tmabpn8d/

Comment: Sorry.. i forgot to share the css. But i have changed the format of the html code. But thanks, i think it works now!

Comment: Your welcome :) If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to mark it as the accepted answer.